# HTTP request to PHP page, trying to login

Tags: java, php, http, session, web-applications

I want to develop a java application to make some processing on a web page, but this page requires a login first. so, I checked the HTML page of the login page, and have now the name of the username and pw fields, the method "post" and ready to make a post request. BUT, the action in the form="" so, I don't know what is the URL I have to request.

is there a solution, is it possible to get the after-login page?! and is it also possible to use the links inside that page to navigate and get more pages?? and if the this site is making a session to handle the use logged in or not, can I pretend to have that session and act like this site???

sorry for the long question.

Comment: Are you talking about web scraping? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping

Comment: The easiest way I've found is to log into the site manually in a browser like Firefox, then open up your cookies and copy them out into your script. There are plenty of PHP libraries that let you download HTML from sites and then you can parse through it in a variety of ways.. XPath, CSS selectors, or just iterating through the elements. Lately I've been using Selenium WebDriver, but it doesn't have any PHP bindings that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 2):

If the form target is empty, it means the form is submitted to the same page.

Answer (score 0):

The `method="post" action="yourScriptToHandleTheLogin.php"` part of the form tells the browser the name of the script that will verify the users credentials. That is where you do the checking in the database and update the session details to give them access. It can be the same file or you can have a different file that will redirect them back after they are verified.